# Is it possible to read a parquet file from a public S3 bucket using R-polars?

Tags: r, parquet, rust-polars

I am testing `polars` implementation in R and I want to read and process (lazily) a parquet file from a public AWS S3 bucket.

After loading

```
library(aws.s3)
library(arrow)
library(polars)
```

I tried to open a connection using `arrow::s3_bucket(url)` where `url` is the location of the parquet file: `s3://rimrep-data-public/091-aims-sst/test-50-64-spatialpart`

```
tempBucket <- s3_bucket(bucket = 's3://rimrep-data-public/091-aims-sst/test-50-64-spatialpart')
df <- scan_parquet(tempBucket)
```

resulted in

```
Error in new_from_parquet(path = file, n_rows = n_rows, cache = cache,  : not a string object
```

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Cheers, Eduardo

**UPDATE:** I tried to read using the S3 URI directly:

```
df <- scan_parquet('s3://rimrep-data-public/091-aims-sst/test-50-64-spatialpart')
```

and get:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'One or more of the cloud storage features ('aws', 'gcp', ...) must be enabled.'
```